# DICOM Dataset not loading correct

Tags: ami.js

I am trying to load a DICOM Series in all three directions (sagital, axial and coronal). The Dataset is oriented axial and displaying all the slices in axial orientation is working fine. But when displaying the sagital and coronal view, AMI.js only renders to the amount of axial slices right. You might better understand what I mean with pictures. So picture one shows the rendering until slice 147 and picture two shows slice 148. The series has 147 DICOM images.

[correct slice displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLve8.png)

[wrong displaying of slice 148](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88H8r.png)

Do you have any idea why this happens and what I have to change, that all slices will be displayed correct? Displaying another set of data, where the DICOMs are in coronal direction, is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshots, it seems that the "intensityAuto" flag on "stackHelper.slice.intensityAuto" is "true".

If "intensityAuto" is "true", the slice "helper" tries to fetch the window level of the related frame. Otherwise, it uses the values from the "stack". In addition, if "intensityAuto" is "true", the window level changes each time you change the slices, which is not what you want to do in most cases.

If you try to fetch window level from a frame that doesn't exist, the behavior is not defined.

That is consistent with your issue, you have 147 "frames", so the slice "helper" is able to retrieve a window level for the first 147 frames in each direction. If you try to access a frame superior to 147, you get unexpected results.

In your case, you should turn "auto intensity" off in all the slice helpers and manage window level yourself. Get the window level from the stack and update the slice helpers manually when you want to adjust the window level.

HTH,
Nicolas

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I can display all the slices now. But actually I am trying to show the data as a 3D representation. I thought this would be the error why i can't display the dataset, but it is still not showing in 3D. @Nicolas do you have an idea what I have to change, to display it in 3D? I can display another set of data in 3D like in the "singlepass" example, but not this one. Might this still has something to do with the intensityAuto flag?

Comment: I'd guess it has to do with the window level if your dataset has negative values - try to use the latest version of ami.js. Please open a new SO question otherwise.